# Objective C Constructer without init

Tags: objective-c, ios, initialization

When I'm creating custom classes, I'd like to be able to skip the alloc init part of the code once I go to construct an instance of the class. Similar to how it's done with:

```
NSString * ex = [NSString stringWithFormat...];
```

Basically I already have the class set up with a custom initializer method to set up my basic variables. However, when I'm on the front end and actually making these critters I have to say:

```
[[Monster alloc] initWithAttack:50 andDefense:45];
```

and I'd rather be able to say

```
[Monster monsterWithAttack:50 andDefense:45];
```

I know it's a simple stupid thing to just get rid of the alloc part but it makes the code more readable so I'd prefer to do it that way. I originally tried just changing my method from

```
-(id)initWithAttack:(int) a andDefense:(int) d
```

to

```
-(id)monsterWithAttack:(int) a andDefense:(int) d
```

and then changing my `self = [super init]` to `self = [[super alloc] init];` but that clearly doesn't work! Any ideas?

Comment: monsterWithAttack must be a class method, so replace - with +

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to make a *class* method

```
+(id)monsterWithAttack:(int) a andDefense:(int) d
```

in which you create, initialize, and return an instance (and don't forget your memory management):

```
+(id)monsterWithAttack:(int) a andDefense:(int) d {
    // Drop the autorelease IF you're using ARC 
    return [[[Monster alloc] initWithAttack:a andDefense:d] autorelease];
}
```

Comment: Ah so I keep the init method and just don't use it in the implementation. Makes perfect sense. Quick question that autorelease part is unnecessary in ARC right?

Comment: I don't use ARC, but as I understand it, yes.

Comment: Alright cool, thanks. It does work without the autorelease in ARC, by the way. Throws an error with it.

Answer (score 6):

What you want is a convenience constructor.  It's a class method that returns a useable instance of a class and allocates memory for it at the same time.

```
-(id)initWithAttack:(int)a andDefense:(int)d;
+(id)monsterWithAttack:(int)a andDefense:(int)d;

+(id)monsterWithAttack:(int)a andDefense:(int)d {
        //-autorelease under MRC
        return [[[self class] alloc] initWithAttack:a andDefense:d];
 }
 -(id)initWithAttack:(int)a andDefense:(int)d {
        self = [super init];
        if (self){
             //custom initialization
        }
        return self;
    }
```

Comment: Ah convenience constructor... if I knew the name I would have probably been able to find it. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You should use a class factory method in the header of monster class.

```
+(id)monsterWithAttack:(int) attackValue andDefense:(int) defenseValue
```

in the implementetation of monster class

```
+(id)monsterWithAttack:(int) attackValue andDefense:(int) defenseValue {
    return [[[[self class] alloc] initWithAttack:attackValue andDefense:defenseValue] autorelease];
}
```

The use of `[self class]` guarantees the correct dispatch during subclassing. If you are using ARC you can avoid the `autorelease` method

Comment: What's the difference between `[[self class] alloc]` and just `[self alloc]`?

Comment: In class method self is related to the class, if you subclass Monster class and you inherit that method you will always create Monster instances. To be sure that you create the correct instance you just ask the class Who are you?

Comment: `[self class]` is unnecessary here; in a class method, `self` is already the class object. `[self alloc]` works perfectly. @Cald

Answer (score 2):

Class methods of this type use `autorelease`.

So for instance, you might say:

```
+ (id)
monsterWithAttack:(int)  a
defense:(int)            d
{
    return [[Monster alloc] initWithAttack:a defense:d]
            autorelease];
}
```